# Team icon's right most part is not visible

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, design

I was curious about the strangely designed team icon in left navigation on SO site. It did not feel right! I inspected and found that a CSS style for right position property is set for -6 which causes the cropping of icon.

See screen shot below with some free hand circles.

Browser: Chrome

[image: See screen shot below]

Comment: PS: Take your time and don't fix it in 6-8 weeks.

Comment: +1 for the shaky double-free-hand-circle - a rare thing nowadays ;)

Comment: btw - you have 8 unread amazon notifications..

Comment: This layout is by design. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is defintely on purpose since the relevant div:

```
<div class="ps-absolute t4 rn6">
```

has the class rn6 assigned to it:

```
.rn6 {
   right: -6px !important;
}
```

Without that class it would look like this:

[image]

Now you could argue why it doesnt have a rp3:

```
.rp3 {
   right: 3px !important;
}
```

which results in a fully visible svg like this:

[image]

But considering possible translations into other languages that take more space would result in the text being covered by the svg like in that example (german):

[image]

So my personal guess is that this is 1.) on purpose and not a broken layout 2.) a comprehendable layout decision.

Design wise it's completely fine to cut things off or hide the overflow - obviously that depends on the specific case..